# Getting error MODULE NOT FOUND in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-web-developer

```
 const express = require("express");
 const app = express();      
 const path = require("path");

 app.use(express.static(staticPath)); 
 let staticPath=path.join(__dirname, "..");
```

these line of code is giving error: Module not found

[image]

Comment: Can you share directory and file structure? Might be your index.js file is missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `Express`  is installed.

Run the following command

```
npm i express --save
```

Also check if you have package.json file in your App's root directory. If there is not then run the following command.

```
npm init
npm i express --save
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make you have initialized npm that will end up creating the package.json file:

```
npm init
```

then install the express library

```
npm i express
```

after that, you are trying to run a file called index.js
Your Node CLI cannot find it in the respected directory
Make sure to fix your run command as follow

```
node .\{FILE_NAME}.js
```